# Session authentication on static files

Tags: php, apache, session

I'm building a web application that requires a user authentication or simply a logged-in user to use most of the application functionality. Till now I forced myself to wrote everything in static files (.html) and wrote a REST API (php) to allow the client-side and server-side communicate and return values per user ID.

Since I'm using static files I can't use php session in the web-page itself and sending AJAX on every page load to check if user's session sounds to me as a wrong code architecture and maybe even a security problem(?).

So I used Google and found out about Apache mod_auth, mod_session, mod_session_cookies & mod_session_crypto but I couldn't find a decent explanation (not to talk about guides or tutorials how to active and use those mods) about the mods and the synergy between them.

I'm a junior coder and lack of experience and I'm turning to StackOverflow's community to help me out chose the right way to handle sessions and those apache's mods.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure there's lots of ways (probably better than this) but you could route all static requests to a PHP handler via `mod_rewrite` and have it check permissions and then serve the appropriate file. It would be seamless from the outside (urls like `/static/js/foo.js`) would look completely fine while logged in. It's worth deciding if this is worth the performance hit (is there really a risk to unauthenticated users fetching static content?)

Comment: But that means I will use PHP engine for every request. This is basically what I tried to avoid when decided not to write my files in php but to use static html files instead. am I right?

Comment: If that's the reason you made the decision then yes obviously you're right, this will incur the overhead of PHP running on every request like I said above. This is just one option off the top of my head. I know it's possible to integrate httpd with PHP's session data, I'm just not sure of how cumbersome (or flexible) that setup is.